# Loop for sticky posts

Tags: loop, sticky-post

I used [Justin Tadlock's](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/28/get-the-latest-sticky-posts-in-wordpress) tutorial on how to create a loop consisting only sticky posts.

The code looked more or less like this:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
rsort( $sticky );
$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 2 );
query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) );
```

According to the tutorial, I simply need to change the last number from the 3rd line to configure how many posts I wanted to display in the loop.

But I think the code above won't let me display number of posts any bigger than what's stored in `posts_per_page` setting `(dashboard -> Settings -> Reading)`

---

So here's the question:

How can I make the query above so that it could display more posts than whatever value the `posts_per_page` option have?

Comment: it seems I just found the answer... I simply need to insert posts_per_page into the query_posts()

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using the function `query_posts` this only queries the default result on that page. It's advised that you use `wp_query` instead, it just eliminates the margin for error or unexpected results.

You can create a new query like below, and specify explicitly how many posts to return:

```
<?php

$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
rsort( $sticky );

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $sticky,
    'posts_per_page' => 10
    );

$sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post();
    // Do stuff with sticky posts
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

This method also allows you to drop the `array_slice` process. So you can simply change posts_per_page to a number of your choice